# Create a new probability distribution (relying on the previous r.v.) in R

Tags: r, function, statistics, probability-density

I want to write this pdf and generate random numbers using it.

Suppose that X is a random variable that takes the values 0 or 1 only, the pdf is as follows:

```
P(X_t) = a^[(1-X_(t-1))*X_t] * (1-a)^[(1-X_(t-1))*(1-X_t)] * b^[X_(t-1)*(1-X_t)] * (1-b)^[X_(t-1)*X_t]
```

`X_t`: the current r.v., `X_(t-1)`: the previous r.v., where t=1,2,...,T and the initial value at t=0 is given. Finally, a and b are two known probabilities.

Comment: It's not clear how X(t) can be dependent on X(t) - per your formula. Should it be X(t) is a function of X(t-1) and X(t-2)?

Comment: No it is a pdf like Bernoulli, i.e. P(x)= p^x . (1-p)^(1-x). So it is usual that the pdf relies on x but what is in this pdf is that it relies on x and the previous x too.

Comment: I just wrote x_t to make it different from the previous one denoted X_(t-1)

Comment: I made a big mistake in my previous answer but I've corrected it now. please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understood, but you could possibly do as follows.

If we say 'y' is the previous realisation, and 'x' is the current one, then we have:

```
P(x=0|y=0) = 1-a
P(x=1|y=0) = a
P(x=0|y=1) = b
P(x=1|y=1) = 1-b
```

So then we can generate uniform variates U in [0,1] and if y = 0 then set x = 0 if U <= 1-a, else x = 1; and if y = 1, then set x = 0 if U <= b, else set x = 1

The following function may do the trick, where x0 is the initial value of x:

```
rhany <- function(n, a, b, x0 = 0) {
    sim <- c(x0, runif(n-1))
    for (i in 2:n){
        sim[i] = (sim[i-1] == 0) * ((sim[i] <= 1-a) * 0 + (sim[i] > a) * 1) + 
                 (sim[i-1] == 1) * ((sim[i] <= b) * 0 + (sim[i] > 1-b) * 1)
    }
    sim
}
```

So then if you run the function:

```
rhany(10, 0.1, 0.7)
[1] 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

Admittedly, the for-loop slows down the function; it takes about 9 seconds on my machine to generate 1e7 variates. You could reimplement using the Rcpp package:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericVector rhanya(double a, double b, NumericVector zs) {
    int n = zs.size();
    NumericVector sim = zs;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        sim[i] = (sim[i-1] == 0) * ((sim[i] <= 1-a) * 0 + (sim[i] > a) * 1) + (sim[i-1] == 1) * ((sim[i] <= b) * 0 + (sim[i] > 1-b) * 1);
    }
    return(sim);
}')

rhany1 <- function(n, a, b, x0 = 0) {
    sim <- c(x0, runif(n-1))
    rhanya(a, b, sim)
}
```

This function rhany1 takes less than 0.5 sec to generate 1e7 variates.

You can test that the two functions rhany and rhany1 give the same results when the same seed is set:

```
set.seed(123); bc <- rhany(1e7, 0.1, 0.7)
set.seed(123); ac <- rhany1(1e7, 0.1, 0.7)
all.equal(ac, bc)
[1] TRUE
```